# Convert JSON child Object to table in Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, sqlite, xamarin.forms

maybe it is a simple question, but I didn't find any solution on the internet.

I have the following json data came from an API:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "6ba8da0c-b307-40b6-b858-5fb1b880d473",
        "nomeCompleto": "João da Silva Jr.",
        "cpf": "12345678910",
        "nomePai": "João da Silva",
        "nomeMae": "Maria da Silva",
        "casado": true,
        "profissao": [
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA13",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 8
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "userId": "b2a2f414-742d-47d5-a0f4-52f1f9849687",
        "nomeCompleto": "Manuel de Souza",
        "cpf": "12345678910",
        "nomePai": "Joaqui de Souza",
        "nomeMae": "Maria Joaquina de Souza",
        "casado": true,
        "profissao": [
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA15",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 8
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "userId": "64549488-5530-4975-8ea9-0f208aa4118d",
        "nomeCompleto": "Yasmin Paulino",
        "cpf": "12345678910",
        "nomePai": "Francisco Paulino",
        "nomeMae": "Joyce Gudowisk",
        "casado": false,
        "profissao": [
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA09",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 3
            },
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA19",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 1
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "userId": "6ba8da0c-b307-40b6-b858-5fb1b880d471",
        "nomeCompleto": "João da Silva Neto.",
        "cpf": "12345678910",
        "nomePai": "João da Silva Jr.",
        "nomeMae": "Maria Antonieta",
        "casado": true,
        "profissao": [
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA10",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 8
            },
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA11",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 3
            },
            {
                "profissaoId": "3B85BE83-9B4E-4B15-9EB2-68363936CA12",
                "anosDeExperiencia": 1
            }
        ]
    }, 
]
```

I need to create 2 SQLite tables with that data in my Xamarin App. First from the root node and the second with the child node, but including the userId for each data object, do you understand?

The intent is to show how many years of experience the user have in some profession.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: first, use json2csharp.com to translate the json into C# classes.  Then use those classes to build a data model

Comment: I did it. to create the classes is not the problem. It is working, but as a new xamarin and c# developer, the only data I was able to insert in the database was the root json node. Do you have an example of code creating a data model joining part o a root and a child json node data?

Comment: posting that code would be extremely helpful

Comment: Break it down to two steps: deserializing json, which seems done, and save object to Sqlite, which depends on how you creat the table, define the model and how insert data. So are you using the NuGet "sqlite-net-pcl"? And post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to create 2 SQLite tables with that data in my Xamarin App. First from the root node and the second with the child node, but including the userId for each data object, do you understand?

I do one sample that using your xxx.json file, convert json data into List<> data, you can take a look.

Firstly, create two model class.

```
 public class UserModel
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string nomeCompleto { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string nomePai { get; set; }
    public string nomeMae { get; set; }
    public bool casado { get; set; }
    public List<Prof> profissao { get; set; }

}
public class Prof
{
    public string profissaoId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public int anosDeExperiencia { get; set; }
}
```

Then foreach  List to add UserId in List

```
 private void getdata()
    {
        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
        List<Prof> profs = new List<Prof>();
        var assembly = typeof(listviewsample.Page24).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FormsSample.user.json");
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list               
            users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserModel>>(jsonString);   
           foreach(UserModel user in users)
            {
                if((user.profissao).Count>0)
                {        
                   foreach(Prof prof in user.profissao)
                    {
                        prof.userId = user.userId;
                        profs.Add(prof);
                    }
                   
                }
            }

           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cherry. That's what I was missing in my code (see it bellow). It worked perfectly.

```
foreach(UserModel user in users)
            {
                if((user.profissao).Count>0)
                {        
                   foreach(Prof prof in user.profissao)
                    {
                        prof.userId = user.userId;
                        profs.Add(prof);
                    }
                   
                }
            }
```